# how can i change the currency sign based on a condition in Microsoft flow?

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, sharepoint-list

I have two columns that depend on each other, one is a calculated column in Microsoft flow. I like to change the currency sign based on the condition of the first column.

```
  |Id  |Japan    |Installment |
  |  1 |  Yes    |   Fee will be billed in 2 equal installments of  ¥6873750 on 1-Apr-2020, 1-Oct-2020    |
  |  2 |  No     |   Fee will be billed in 2 equal installments of $6873750 on 1-Apr-2020, 1-Oct2020      |
```

My installment column is a calculated column, in my current logic it only puts a dollar sign whether Japan is Yes or No, but for the future when the Japan column is "Yes" I like to make the currency into Yen( ¥). here is the logic

```
=IF([Number of Installments]>="2","Fee will be billed in "&[Number of Installments]&" equal installments of "&"$"&ROUNDUP([Installment Value],2)&" on "&TEXT([Installment 1],"d-mmm-yyyy")&", "&TEXT([Installment 2],"d-mmm-yyyy")
```

Comment: is the Installment column calculated in the power app or in Flow/Power Automate?  Your question is asking for how to do it in Flow, but the code shown looks like Power Apps.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your SharePoint Calculated column to be like:

```
=IF([Number of Installments]>="2","Fee will be billed in "&[Number of Installments]&" equal installments of "& IF([Japan],"¥","$") & ROUNDUP([Installment Value],2)&" on "&TEXT([Installment 1],"d-mmm-yyyy")&", "&TEXT([Installment 2],"d-mmm-yyyy")
```

You add the **& IF([Japan],"¥","$") &** between the text.

The same logic can be applied in Power Automate (MS Flow) based on the "Japan" Column in a conditional action

[image]